# Interface without mutating the receiver

Tags: go

I want to define an interface that has a method that returns a value whose type is the interface itself.

I tried to define the interface like this:

```
type Event interface {
}

type Entity interface {
    ApplyEvent(command Event) (Entity, error)
}
```

And I would like to make a struct implement the Entity interface by doing:

```
type ShoppingList struct {
}

func (list ShoppingList) ApplyEvent(event Event) (ShoppingList, error) {
    // code that changes "list" goes here.
    return list, nil
}
```

If I do that and then try to pass a ShoppingList to a function that expects an Entity I get the following error:

```
func main() {
    test(ShoppingList{})
}

func test(e Entity) {
}

Cannot use 'ShoppingList{}' (type ShoppingList) as type Entity. 
Type does not implement 'Entity' 
need method: ApplyEvent(command Event) (Entity, error) 
have method: ApplyEvent(event Event) (ShoppingList, error)
```

I know I could define the interface and the receiver like this instead:

```
type Event interface {
}

type Entity interface {
    ApplyEvent(command Event) error
}

type ShoppingList struct {
}

func (list *ShoppingList) ApplyEvent(event Event) error {
    // code that changes "list" goes here.
    return nil
}
```

But I would prefer to write the code using pure functions and immutable data structures as much as possible.

I want to return the changed value instead of mutating the receiver.

What would be the way to do it in Go?

Comment: You aren't really implementing the function. The signature of the function for the interface is: `ApplyEvent(command Event) (Entity, error)` and for the `ShoppingList` it's `ApplyEvent(event Event) (ShoppingList, error)`.

Comment: (It needs to return an `Entity`, which won't be guaranteed to be the same concrete type.)

Comment: …in other words, to add to what others have said: Go does not have neither "generics" (C#- or Java-style) nor "templates" (C++ style). It most probably will have generics by v2.0 though. Go's interfaces are very real _values,_ not some sort of abstract placeholders which get "parameterized". I highly recommend [this doc](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) by one of the Go devs; the doc is a little bit rusty (Go does not anymore embed pointer-sized values directly into interface values) but crispy clear and up to the point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you probably already know this.  But just in case you haven't thought of it yet, you could also write it like this:

```
type Event interface {
}

type Entity interface {
    ApplyEvent(command Event) (Entity, error)
}

type ShoppingList struct {
}

func (list ShoppingList) ApplyEvent(event Event) (Entity, error) {
    //...
    return list
}
```

Here, I'm doing the same `return` but I'm returning it "as" an `Entity` interface rather than a `ShoppingList`.  If it was relevant that the `Entity` was a shopping list later, I could attempt a type assertion if I wanted to see if the `Entity` was a `ShoppingList` later in the code.

But it would be more consistent with the `interface` concept to provide an interface method for the `ShoppingList` to do its thing by merit of it being an *Entity* rather than a consumer enumerating all possible entities.  After all, why would the "Event" applied to a "ShoppingList" necessarily yield another "ShoppingLIst"?  Couldn't it generate, for example, an InstacartInvoice instead?  Of course, at this point I'm well beyond the scope of your question.  But any time the type of an interface's concrete value is relevant to a consumer, try very hard to make it relevant to a method of that interface instead.   Just like you did with `ApplyEvent`.

Comment: I am new to Go and I think the thing I am struggling with is how do you define a generic concrete behaviour that can be specialized later? In Java or Typescript you would define a class with the generic behaviour and abstract methods that should be implemented by the subclasses. How would you do it in Go?

Comment: a go `interface` is *kind of* like an abstract class in that it defines the signature of methods but doesn't define them.  However, the similarity ends there.  The idea of composing concrete classes by extending abstract base classes is more like embedding structs (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).